# *.aspx Control to display HTML from string loaded via codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am looking for aspx control that can easly allow me to fill it with html. HTML is in string in code behind. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use Literal control

In Markup view use this:

```
<asp:Literal ID="LiteralAlert" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

and in codebehind:

```
LiteralMainHTML.Text = "<p>lol!!!</p>";
```